# How to change SQLAlchemy UniqueConstraint size which is by default 64 bytes?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to setup role-permission based authorization in my application. The model for one of my many tables(role, permission, user, etc) is as given below

```
class UserRole(Model):

    __tablename__ = 'user_role'

    id = Column(String(36), primary_key=True, default=_generate_unique_business_id)
    user_id = Column(String(36), ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    role_id = Column(String(36), ForeignKey('role.id'), nullable=False)

    created_on = Column(DateTime, default=_get_date_time)
    modified_on = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False, server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))
    deleted_on = Column(DateTime)

    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('user_id', 'role_id', name='_user_role_uc'),)
```

NOTE - Primary keys in my tables are `Strings` because I put `UUIDs` there.

Now that my authorization is ready, I want to make it backward compatible. For that I want to populate rows in `role_permission` table using `user` and `role` tables. So I decided to run below `insert` query manually.

```
INSERT INTO user_role (id, user_id, role_id, created_on) SELECT uuid(), user.id, 'e5d7454f-a58b-4a0d-acae-074890dadb84', now() FROM user;
```

But I get an error saying

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '604fdff9-a402-11e5-b430-28d24442d3e7-e5d7454f-a58b-4a0d-acae-074' for key '_user_role_uc'
```

Ideally this shouldn't have happened.

When I compared the expected and actual size of this unique constraint, I found that

```
expected = size of user id + size of role id
         = '604fdff9-a402-11e5-b430-28d24442d3e7' + '-' + 'e5d7454f-a58b-4a0d-acae-074890dadb84'
         = 36+36 = 72
actual   = size of '604fdff9-a402-11e5-b430-28d24442d3e7-e5d7454f-a58b-4a0d-acae-074' = 64
```

Why the discrepancy? Is the default size of unique constraint 64 char/bytes? Even if it is what's the problem? How to modify that? I read the [sqlalchemy-doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#unique-constraint) but didn't find a way.

I can't think of any other reason but this discrepancy. Please help.